# Can't mount my USB Drive

Tags: usb, mount, drive

```
~> sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Disk 
Did not find any restart pages in $LogFile and it was not empty.
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
```

I have a USB Hard Disk and Windows can't detect it. So I tried to open it up on Ubuntu using gparted. Gparted detects the NTFS partition, so everything seems to be fine (note, though, that the total size of the files in this disk is over 1 TB).

I tried to mount it using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Disk
```

But I got:

```
Did not find any restart pages in $LogFile and it was not empty.
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
```

Then, the process just sits there blinking. Any ideas on how to fix it? It's taking forever (> 10 minutes), should I wait or cancel it and do something else?

Thank you in advance.